# How to convert DHHN2016 to mean sea level?

Tags: raster, dem, srtm, topography

I am new to GIS. How can I convert DHHN2016 to mean sea level?

I am using this dataset https://www.opengeodata.nrw.de/produkte/geobasis/hm/dgm1_xyz/dgm1_05314000_Bonn_EPSG4647_XYZ.zip which I stiched together to one geotiff.

Comment: DHHN2016 is gravity-related so should be close to MSL anyway. "MSL" is a very generic term. Do you mean convert to EGM2008 or EGG2015?

Comment: I have this data and some SRTM .hgt tiles I want to compare. I am not sure which of the two choices, EGM2008 or EGG2015, would be more appropriate. Or how to do such a conversion.